# Yii: TbCollapse multi link (href = #collapse and update status to be="1")

Tags: javascript, yii

in this issue, i use booster widgets tbcollapse to make some like a inbox in message menu, unread or new message is have status 0, so when i click the panel title in collapse widgets, it will open div with id #collapse, and change the status in database to be 1 (readed), its possible??? how?

```html
<?php $collapse = $this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbCollapse');
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
 <?php for ($a = 0; $a<count($pesan); $a++){ ; ?>
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $a ;?>">
   <?php echo $pesan[$a]["sender"] ;?>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<?php echo $a ;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
    <?php echo $pesan[$a]["message"] ;?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <?php }; ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstrap's collapse events to trigger an ajax call, for what you want probably the best option is the shown.bs.collapse event, for example:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  //Get the id of the message and use ajax to update the database      
});
```

**Edit #1**

A little example:

First add a custom id to your widget

```
<?php $collapse = $this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbCollapse',
array('id'=>"myCollapsible")
);?>
```

At the end of your view add a script tag, or you can register a script with yii's CClientScript. For the sake of simplicity I will use script tags

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var target=$(e.target);//get shown element
    if(target.attr('id')===$(this).attr('id'))return;//Event is fired on page load, ignore event on main collapse
      $.post('controllerUrl',{messageId:$(e.target).attr("id")},function(data){//call server to update 
       //do something if everything was ok or display error
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

In your controller just add a method to update the message status

```
public function actionUpdateMessage{
   MessageModel::model()->updateByPK($_POST['messageId'],'viewed'=>'1');//update the model whose id was sent, provide some validation if needed
   return;//end processing
}
```

Hope this helps

**Edit #2**

In case you need to put more metadata for the ajax call, I recommend to use data attributes in your elements, so for example you could add an Id based on your database

```
<div id="collapse<?php echo $a ;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse"
   data-messageId="<?php echo $pesan[$a]["id"] ;?>">
  <div class="panel-body">
   <?php echo $pesan[$a]["message"] ;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the javascript code you can retrieve the info with data method like the following

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var target=$(e.target);//get shown element
    if(target.attr('id')===$(this).attr('id'))return;//Event is fired on page load, ignore event on main collapse
      $.post('controllerUrl',{messageId:$(e.target).data("messageId")},function(data){//call server to update 
       //do something if everything was ok or display error
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Edit #3**

If retrieving data attributes using jquery data method doesn't work, you still can access these attributes using attr method

```
 $.post('controllerUrl',{messageId:target.attr("data-messageId")},function(data){//call server to update 
   //do something if everything was ok or display error
  });
```

If the data attributes aproach doesn't work, you can also try with hidden fields like this:

Firs, instead of setting data-messageId attribute, add inside your panel-collapse div an input hidden like the following:

```
<div id="collapse<?php echo $a ;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pesan[$a]["id"] ;?>"/>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <?php echo $pesan[$a]["message"] ;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, change the following in the javascript:

```
$.post('controllerUrl',{messageId:target.find("input").val()},function(data){//call server to update 
   //do something if everything was ok or display error
  });
```

Comment: not work yet, i think id not define, id primary key is from $pesan[$a]["id"],

Comment: nothing change @pablo, messageId is still not define... i try define directly, but still doesnt change..   $.post('controllerUrl',{messageId:1},function(data){
      });

Comment: ¿How are you retrieving the messageId in your controller?, also ¿is the url really controllerUrl?, I would recommend using the createUrl like this: <?php echo $this->createUrl('controllerAction')?>